# fwrite() error: supplied argument is not a valid stream resource. Why?

Tags: php, warnings

I have this code:

```
$file = '/path/to/file.txt';

if (($fd = fopen($file, "a") !== false)) {
    fwrite($fd, 'message to be written' . "\n");
    fclose($fd);
}
```

Why do I get the following warnings?

```
fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your if statement is wrong. Try

```
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) {
```

Because yours one is like

```
$fd = fopen($file, "a") !== false
```

Comment: Ups... I missed that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a parenthesizing error. The code should read:

```
if (($fd = fopen($file, "a")) !== false) {
```

What the current code does is set `$fd` to the result of comparing the `fopen` return value with `false`, which is also `false` (assuming the `fopen` succeeds). In effect you have

```
if ($fd = false) {
```

which is self-explanatory and also testable (with `var_dump`).

**The moral of the story**: Don't assign values to variables inside `if` conditions. This is not 1980, and you are not programming in C. Just say no and make the core *readable*; it will love you for it.